Capacitor-Swift.h file not found in Xcode - CocoaPods & Capacitor Build Issues
I'm working on a project that uses Capacitor and CocoaPods in Xcode (16.1) and I'm getting several error messages when building, including: ‘Capacitor/Capacitor-Swift.h file not found‘ “Cannot define category for undefined class ”CAPPluginCall’‘ “Cannot find interface declaration for ”CAPPluginCall’‘ “No known class method for selector ”jsDateFormatter’’ Additionally, there is a warning: run script build phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks” is executed on every build because it does not specify any output.
Picture of the problem
I have already taken the following steps to solve the problem: Reinstalled CocoaPods with pod install. In the build settings made sure that Defines Module is set to ‘Yes’ Unfortunately the errors still persist. Are there any specific settings or steps I could have overlooked to correctly include the Capacitor-Swift.h file and fix the other errors?
Details:
Xcode version: 16.1
Capacitor version: 6.1.2
CocoaPods-Version: 1.15.2
Dependencies:
{
  "name": "MYAPP",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "6.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "6.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "6.0.1",
    "@ionic/react": "^8.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/dom": ">=7.21.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^5.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "terser": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "~5.2.0",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

Any help or ideas to solve these problems would be greatly appreciated!

Try check in your ios/App folder, and see if there got this folder :
cordova folder
If you had it, run :
cd ios/App
pod install

It should install all of the cordova folders and then just build normally :
pod install
If you dont have the folder from the first picture, what i did is kinda scuffed but well, it works.. I created a new ionic project to get that folder and copied to my main project folder.
Hope it helps !
